# Recyclerview Click

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I created a list, I want to Implement a clickListener
but the problem that the click is not captured

```
    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView design, ip, port, number, id;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
        design = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_device_designation);
        port = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_device_port);
        ip = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_device_ip);
        number = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_device_number);
        id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_device_id);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.i("Test", "Test");
    }
}
```

Now I want if I click on the menu icon, I want a menu appears from the bottom
I managed to get the click of the button and the position but can you help me bring up the menu

[My Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGUx5.png)

```
public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
        design = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_device_designation);
        port = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_device_port);
        ip = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_device_ip);
        number = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_device_number);
        id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_device_id);
        imageViewContextMenu = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_context_menu);
        linearLayoutDeviceClick = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutDeviceClick);

        imageViewContextMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("Test", String.valueOf(getPosition())); //Test succes
            }
        });

        linearLayoutDeviceClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("TestLayout", String.valueOf(getPosition())); //Test succes

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: check this: http://www.littlerobots.nl/blog/Handle-Android-RecyclerView-Clicks/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to **setOnClickListener** after **findViewById**

1. if you want to create **on click for whole item** you can **findViewById**
   your **root-layout** like relativelayout or linearlayout etc. and then set onclicklistner
2. if you want to create on click for **specific view** you can **findViewById** your **view**  and then set onclicklistner

Answer (score 1):

add onItemTouchListener to your recycler view.

```
 mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(mActivity, mRecyclerView, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position)
                    {
                        ///////// add your task
                    }


                    });
```

Comment: if it is helpful to you .Accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform your click listener in onBindViewHolder() or in onCreateViewHolder() of your recyclerview adapter.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        //perform your operations here
        }
 });

}
```

Where itemView is your view for each item in recyclerview.Use

```
holder.buttonName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        //perform your operations here
        }
 });

}
```

to perform a button click inside the view.